# self organizing map codes plot

Tags: r

plot(supersom, type="codes")

warning messages:
In par(opar) : argument 1 does not name a graphical parameter

how to get rid of from the above warning?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
suppressWarnings(plot(supersom, type="codes"))
```